# Sub Query or Join MySQL?

Tags: mysql, compare, rows

table league

```
team_id name        wins    losses  played  recorded    created
1       dodgers     10      4       14      1364790000  1353215830
2       angels      9       6       15      1364790000  1353661376
3       pirates     12      3       15      1364790000  1353543466

team_id name        wins    losses  played  recorded    created
1       dodgers     22      9       31      1367274480  1353215830
2       angels      14      17      31      1367274480  1353661376
3       pirates     19      13      32      1367274480  1353543466
4       yankees     10      9       19      1367274480  1365577298
5       brewers     7       11      18      1367274480  1365394448
```

Would like Results as:

```
team_id name        wins    losses  played
1       dodgers     12      5       17      
2       angels      5       11      16
3       pirates     7       10      17
4       yankees     10      9       19
5       brewers     7       11      18
```

I've tried several queries with joins and have had no success.  Every day the team, wins, lossed and played are captured and time stamped on the recorded column.  The team was created on the created column.  (All unix timestamps)  There are several rows in between the 2 dates I'm trying for, but I don't need them for this query.

What I wanted to do was to get April's Won/Loss/Played for existing and new teams, I tried several queries, here are a couple that did not give me the desired results:

```
SELECT a.name as name, a.wins-b.wins as wins, a.losses-b.losses as losses, a.played-b.played as played from league a join league b on a.id=b.id where a.recorded= 1367274480 and b.recorded= 1364790000
```

and

```
SELECT new.*, new.wins-old.wins as newwins, new.losses-old.losses as newlosses FROM league new LEFT JOIN league old ON new.id=old.id WHERE (new.recorded=1367274480 and old.recorded=1364790000) or (new.created > 1364790000 and new.recorded=1367274480) GROUP BY new.id
```

Comment: What datatype is used for the `recorded` and `created` columns?  Are they supposed to be some sort of date-time representation?

Comment: They are unix_timestamp()'ed versions of dates stored as ints.

Comment: You do know, I hope, that a "timestamp" is **NOT** a date-time value, but a reference-counter to support optimistic locking. It cannot be used to reliably regenerate a date-time.

Comment: Unless, of course, you meant to say UNIX seconds from 12::00 am Jan 1, 1970.

Comment: Ask OP, I just merely answered what's that. Besides, we don't always have the freedom to choose database schema.

Comment: Yes, I was going for UNIX seconds from 1/1/1970 00:00.  I should have dropped the schema in my post too.  Thank you both for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want every row for the later records and the same number of rows for the earlier, so you need to use LEFT JOIN to get NULL's for teams created between two dates, but `WHERE recorded` condition for the smaller table should be moved as `ON` condition for the join.

Also keep in mind that `2-NULL = NULL`, so you need to change NULL's into 0's with coalesce().

```
SELECT a.name AS name, 
       a.wins - COALESCE( b.wins, 0 ) AS wins, 
       a.losses - COALESCE( b.losses, 0 ) AS losses, 
       a.played - COALESCE( b.played, 0 ) AS played
FROM league a LEFT JOIN league b 
ON a.team_id = b.team_id AND b.recorded =1364790000
WHERE a.recorded =1367274480
```

Comment: Thank you!  That works beautifully.  I was out in left field, I really appreciate you answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

The way the data is set up, it seems that you don't have a recorded value on each day.  However, each column would be increasing, so you can take the difference between the max and min vals for the month.

Try this:

```
SELECT l.name as name,
       max(l.wins)-min(l.wins) as wins,
       max(l.losses)-min(l.losses) as losses,
       max(l.played)-min(l.played) as played
from league l
where l.recorded <= 1367274480 and l.recorded >= 1364790000
group by l.name
```

Comment: That works for teams that were created and played before April, but not for the teams that started in April.  The date span was flipped on your answer also.  I thank you for your time!